# Exception handling in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, exception, logging

In Magento 1 I was able to catch exceptions and log them into the `exception.log` file using `Mage::logException($e);`

Now, in Magento 2, I can `catch (\Exception $e)` but what do I do with the caught exception? How do I log it into the `exception.log`? Or what is the typical way to handle this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest way to start logging your exceptions would be to inject the `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` into your class's constructor:

```
private $logger;

public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

And then in your `catch` statement:

```
public function doSomething()
{
    try {
        /* Some logic that could throw an Exception */
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Anything else related to how to react after an exception has been caught shouldn't be any different between M1 and M2. Your strategy would also be very specific to your exception handling use case.

Comment: Pro tip: M2 has support for directly passing the exception: `$this->logger->debug($e)`.

Comment: Actually to log exceptions need to use the `critical()` method instead `debug()`

Comment: getMessage should be a function call: getMessage()

Comment: @LM_Fielding Good catch, fixed.

Comment: @jonijones My mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Magento2 has different types of Exception handlers, for example:

- `StateException`
- `InputException`
- `InvalidEmailOrPasswordException`
- `MailException`
- `NotFoundException`
- `ValidatorException`

Etc.

All handler types and their classes exist in [`\vendor\magento\framework\Exception`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Exception).

You need to choose the relevant Exception handler for your requirements and use that.